# How does Impractical Jokers get the permission to be in places like IKEA?

Tags: production, impractical-jokers

How do the people on [Impractical Jokers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impractical_Jokers) get brand-name places to allow them to come in and act stupid and bother their customers?

### update

To be clear they do things that a person could press charges over. Touching, saying perverse things, etc

Comment: Possibly because any publicity is good publicity.

Comment: What Bobby said. The place gets advertised on TV (with possible payment) and they [get their permission in advance](http://www.examiner.com/article/interview-with-joe-gatto-of-impractical-jokers-on-tru-tv).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that in the early days of the show, while they needed permission to enter the stores, they were [largely left to their own devices](http://www.examiner.com/article/interview-with-joe-gatto-of-impractical-jokers-on-tru-tv) to do the actual comedy <sup><sub>(hat tip to @walt for the quote link)</sub></sup>

> **Q. Do you need permission to go to stores and malls?**
>
> *A. Oh yeah, clearance
> is necessary, but **once we are there; they leave us alone and just let
> us blend in without blowing our cover***

Now that the show is more popular, the owners are aware of the likely consequences and [actively welcome them in](http://cltampa.com/artbreaker/archives/2015/01/28/a-qanda-with-tenderloins-impractical-jokers-member-brian-quinn) via their producers:

> **Q. How do you get permission to get into all these places like dentists’ offices, businesses, fast food joints ... ?**
>
> *A. We have a team that that sorta reaches out — I mean it’s a lot easier now because we have people that are just fans of the show, so they
> want us there.*